# How to export a frame-by-frame animation?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create a 3D text loader for a Unity3d application. Using some scripting I've made a Blender file that would set the text property according to current frame.

[image]

Now I want to export it ( hopefully as an FBX file ) into Unity3D and then manually select the current frame of the animation.

My problem is that no matter what options I choose, the FBX exported only exports the current frame in the scene. Exporting the OBJ animation produces 100 different  OBJ files that takes around 16 MB of disk space (too fat to be a loader).

Is there a way to export a frame-by-frame animation from Blender?

Comment: Have you tried Alembic?

Comment: Alembic seems to export just fine, but Unity3d doesn't officially support Alembic yet. I will try the beta version though, although that's not ideal. Still, thanks for showing me that option!